# Error "Aplicación no Instalada" en ningún dispositivo

Tags: java, android-studio, apk, exportar, emulador

-He creado varias aplicaciones en Android estudio y cuando las exporto sin ningún problema ya sea en debug
o en release
no se me instalan en ningún dispositivo, incluyendo el que tengo anclado al android
estudio que si puedo ver los cambios conectado
al mismo, pero después tampoco se me instala. -Ya revisé que estuviera activo los Orígenes Desconocidos-El nivel de la API no puede ser pues no se me instala en ningún dispositivo.-En mi dispositivo ya desinstalé completamente la app de prueba para instalar la apk
y nada, borre (Cache) y nada, no se que más hacer.-Vivo en Cuba pero igual ya también probé activando VPN

Comment: Menciones "no se me instalan en ningún dispositivo", y luego mencionas "En mi dispositivo ya desinstalé completamente la app de prueba ", entonces si se instaló previamente o no?

Comment: No se muestra conectado el dispositivo en Android Studio o sí? Cual es la configuración de tu build.gradle? Revisaste el LogCat o el Log de Android Studio?

Comment: Jorgesys disculpa la incoherencia, cuando tengo el Android estudio abierto y el teléfono conectado puedo ver la app y sus cambios al implementar alguna función nueva, ahora el APK que exporto ni en mi teléfono deja instalar, espero me entiendan ahora, si hace falta poner algún código me dicen pero no sé cuál le podría interesar revisar según el problema!!! Saludos